# Getting a Keystone of Trials, do the whole rift have to played on T1+ or only killing the Rift Guardian?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

I am trying to obtain a Keystone of Trials to test the new greater rifts that was recently added to Diablo 3 on my Xbox One through the 2.1 patch.

Do I have to play the whole rift on T1 (or higher) or is it enough that the game is on T1 (or higher) difficulty when I kill the rift guardian?

Meaning, could I do this:

- Start the gaming session on Master difficulty
- Lower it to hard, and start a normal rift
- Play the normal rift up to about 98-99% completion, then switch to T1
- Kill the last minions and then the rift guardian

And if that works, can I even do this:

- Start my gaming session on T2
- Lower it to T1, and start a normal rift
- Play the rift up to and including *almost* killing the guarding, getting him close to death
- Set the game up to T3, and kill him, to increase the chance of him giving me the keystone?

I'm playing alone right now so I can easily pause the game to change the difficulty.

I'm assuming that plowing through the minions on a lower difficulty is going to be faster than doing them on a higher one, but will this remove my chance of getting the keystone?

Comment: I don't know about the Xbox version but on the PC version you can't raise the difficulty to Torment I or above during a game. Going back to the main menu would reset the rift progress.

Comment: On Xbox One I can change the difficulty up one or down one from whatever I started the game session on. I tried this during a rift now. I created the session on T1, upped to T2, started the rift, lowered to master, played to 98%, upped to T1, got rift guardian to nearly dead, upped to T2, and killed him. No keystone, but that can just be chance.